# If the token recieved is valid how can we call the nominate.js component from existing component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

How can I call the `nominate.js` component if the token is valid from an existing `CreateLink`  component  ?

`CreateLink.js`

```
    const CreateLink = () => {
    const [isFormCreated, setIsFormCreated] = useState(false);
    const onClickEnableForm = () => setIsFormCreated(true);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [token, setToken] = useState("");
    const [tokenUrl, setTokenUrl] = useState("");
    const { handleSubmit, register, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = () => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                localStorage.setItem("userEmail", email);
                const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/createlink', { email, token});
                if (res.data) {
                    console.log("Link token created:" + res.data);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData(); 
    }

    const validateLink = () =>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const email = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
                const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink', { params: { email} });
                if (res.data) {
                    const validToken = res.data[0].token;
                    // if the token is valid, how can call the `nominate.js` component from  here 
                    // by attaching the token to the url ?
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData(); 
    }

    return (
       
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Create Link</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="linkForm inputForm">
                <div className="inputField" >
                    <input name="email" 
                    placeholder="email" 
                    type="text" 
                    value={email}
                    {...register('email',{
                        required: "Email is required",
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                          message: "Invalid email address"
                        }
                      })}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <span className="loginErrorTextFormat">{errors.email && <p>{errors.email.message}</p>}</span> 
                </div>
                <div className="inputField" >
                    <input placeholder="token" 
                    name="token" 
                    type="text" 
                    value={token}
                    {...register('token',{
                        required: "Token is required"
                      })}
                    onChange={(e) => setToken(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <span className="loginErrorTextFormat">{errors.token && <p>Input is not valid</p>}</span> 
                </div>
                <span className="getlinkbutton">
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </span><br></br>
                <span className="getlinkbutton">
                    <button type="button" onClick={validateLink}>Get Link</button>
                </span>
                {
                    <div className="linkdetails nominationlink">
                        {tokenUrl}
                    </div>
                }
            </form>
            
        </div>

    )
}

export default CreateLink
```

`nominate.js`

```
const formFields = [
    ["Name of Nominee", "nominate someone"],
    ["email", "nominee email"],
    ["description", "reason for nomination"],
    ["nominatedby", "nominated by"]
];
const Nominate = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Nominate</h1>
            <form className="linkForm inputForm">
                    {formFields.map(([name, value]) => {
                        return (
                        <div className="inputField" key={name}>
                            { 
                            name === "description" ? (
                                <textarea  placeholder={value} name={name} />
                            ) : (
                                <input placeholder={value} name={name} type="text" />
                            ) }
                        </div>
                        );
                    })}
                    <span className="nominatebutton">
                    <input type="submit" />
                    </span>
                    
                </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nominate
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import "./cssmodules/dashboard.css";
import "./cssmodules/createLink.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import CreateLink from "./components/createLink";
import Nominate from "./components/nominate";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div>
          <div className="navbar-nav">
            <a><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> <b>Dashboard</b> </Link></a>
            <a><Link to={'/createLink'} className="nav-link"> <b>Create Link</b> </Link></a>
          </div>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
              <Route exact path='/createLink' component={CreateLink} />
              <Route exact path='/nominate' component={Nominate} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: By "call the `nominate.js` component" do you mean you want to render the `Nominate` component somewhere? Are you wanting to navigate to the `Nominate` component? What do React hooks have to do with this?

Comment: Yes I would like to render nominate.js by adding the token to the url `https://localhost:3000/nominate/<token>`

Comment: What are you using for routing/navigation in your app? You would just need to PUSH/REPLACE the new path and let the route handle rendering the `Nominate` component.

Comment: Using `react-router-dom` in App.js for routing, but I am bit stuck from where I need to push the new path ? Can I use <Navllink> to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send additional route parameters to the `Nominate` component then I suggest the following changes:

1. Edit the `path='/nominate'` path to accept a token parameter.

   ```
   <Route path='/nominate/:token' component={Nominate} />
   ```
2. Update `Nominate` to consume the route params from the `match` object.

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   const Nominate = () => {
     const { token } = useParams();

     return (
       <div>
         <h1>Nominate</h1>
         <form className="linkForm inputForm">
           ...
         </form>
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```
3. Use the `history` object to issue an imperative navigation in `CreateLink` component.

   ```
   import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

   const CreateLink = () => {
     const history = useHistory();

     ...

     const validateLink = () =>{
       const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
           const email = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
           const res = await Axios.post(
             'http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink',
             { params: { email} },
           );
           if (res.data) {
             const validToken = res.data[0].token;
             if (/* token is valid */) {
               history.push(`/nominate/${validToken}`); // <-- navigate
             }
           }
         } catch (e) {
           console.log(e);
         }
       }
       fetchData(); 
     }
   ```